# HTTP server logging two times for a single request

Tags: javascript, server, path, request, response

I have created a server with http.createServer().

and listening at the port 8000

i have used like for every request, console.log("Request") and end the response by res,end(`Welcome User..`).

But for every request made in port 8000 resulting in two times logging the **Request** output in terminal

[Here is the image of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVzXo.png)

this is the code and  output

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Check the Network tab in the browser to be sure it's only sending one request. It might be sending an OPTIONS request before POST.

Comment: or a request for `favicon.ico`